# async replacement in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I had read many articles about that async is not user friendly but in the following procedure everything messed up when I remove async because it needs one by one execution.

```
for (var k = 0; k < selectedValueArr.length - 1; k++) {
    var value = selectedValueArr[k];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: dm + "Services/AjaxService.asmx/GetCityCheck",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ code: value }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            html += '<li style="height: 25px;"><div style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #91c8e2; padding: 3px 3px; font-size: 13px;">' + document.getElementById('stateName' + selectedValueArr[k]).innerHTML + '</div></li>';
            var datafromServer = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d.toString());
            $.each(datafromServer, function(key, value) {
                html += '<li style="height: 18px; font-size: 12px;"><span pvalue="' + key + '"><input id="chkCity' + key + '" type="checkbox" title="' + value + '" style="border: 0px;" onchange="javascript:CityCheck(this)"><span title="' + value + '" id="cityName' + key + '">' + value + '</span></span></li>';
            });
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the replacement for async because it really hangs the browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an advice: instead of hammering your server with many AJAX requests in a loop it's better to send all the data in a single AJAX request even if more data will transmit through the wire. It's always better to minimize server roundtrips.

So get rid of the for loop and then send a single AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: dm + 'Services/AjaxService.asmx/GetCityCheck',
    data: JSON.stringify({ codes: selectedValueArr }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        // work with data.d directly here, don't do any $.parseJSON
        // see below for how you need to modify your WebMethod for
        // this to work
        ...
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus);
    }
});
```

and then modify your WebMethod so that it takes an array as input parameter and returns an array as output:

```
[WebMethod]
public SomeModel[] GetCityCheck(string[] codes)
{
    ...    
}
```

Notice that if your WebMethod returns directly a model instead of a string you don't need to do any `jQuery.parseJSON` inside your success callback but directly work with `data.d`.

And if you don't want to follow my advice and kill your server with AJAX requests in a loop you will have to capture the `k` indexer variable in a closure:

```
for (var k = 0; k < selectedValueArr.length - 1; k++) {
    (function(i) {
        var value = selectedValueArr[i];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: dm + "Services/AjaxService.asmx/GetCityCheck",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ code: value }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            context: value,
            success: function(data) {
                html += '<li style="height: 25px;"><div style="font-weight: bold; background-color: #91c8e2; padding: 3px 3px; font-size: 13px;">' + document.getElementById('stateName' + this).innerHTML + '</div></li>';
                var datafromServer = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d.toString());
                $.each(datafromServer, function(key, value) {
                    html += '<li style="height: 18px; font-size: 12px;"><span pvalue="' + key + '"><input id="chkCity' + key + '" type="checkbox" title="' + value + '" style="border: 0px;" onchange="javascript:CityCheck(this)"><span title="' + value + '" id="cityName' + key + '">' + value + '</span></span></li>';
                });
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    })(k);
}
```

Also notice how I am using the `context` parameter to the AJAX request in order to pass the value to the success callback. Then inside this success callback I have replaced the `selectedValue[k]` with this because the current context is now different. This is the proper way to pass information to the success callback from the outer context of the $.ajax call.

Comment: How can I put multiple array's in one array (SomeModel)?

Comment: You could use a two dimensional array: `SomeModel[][]` or `List<SomeModel[]>` if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it like this:
- remove async: fals
- remove for loop
- rewrite your server method to accept multiple 'codes' and output array of results
- send to server all requested 'codes' at once
- and when you got your results, iterate through each 'code' result and do with it, what you want to do